# JWT stored in cookie - security concerns

Tags: rest, security, cookies, jwt, single-page-application

I'm building SPA app with server side rendering, using JWT-based authentication.

Current implementation is:

- JWT token is issued and transferred to client after successful username and password verification
- token is then stored in cookie (not `HttpOnly`) - the purpose of that is to avoid the need to login again after full refresh or closing page
- logging out deleted cookie with token
- `Authorization` header is attached to every API request if token exists
- full SSL traffic

I can't store token in LocalStorage because of server side rendering, also the there is no `HttpOnly` because I need to access cookie in order to construct `Authorization` header.

What are the possibilities of stealing the token in such architecture?

Answer (score 1):

One major risk is that any single cross-site scripting vulnerability in your application could be used to steal the token from the cookie, because it's not httpOnly (while I understand why that is the case). XSS in a javascript-heavy application like an SPA is very common and hard to avoid.

Also you're saying the token is kept in the cookie so that after closing the browser, the user is still logged in. On the one hand, that's bad practice, a user closing the browser probably expects being logged out. On the other hand, this means the cookie is persisted to disk, so it is much easier for an attacker to steal it from the client.

Another thing that comes to mind is cross-site request forgery (CSRF), but if I understand correctly, authentication is actually based on the `Authorize` header, where the token is copied in each request. If that's the case, CSRF is not an issue for you (but it would be, if sending the token in the cookie was enough).

So at the very least, I think you should

- not use a persisted cookie for the token
- try to minimize the chance of XSS (eg. by automatically scanning your code, but that will never be 100%, also by carefully choosing secure by default technologies)
- make sure auhentication is based on the `Authorize` header and not the cookie

Still mainly because of the XSS risk, I would probably not recommend doing it this way in a security-critical application.

Comment: In fact (correct me if I'm wrong) the token in being sent via cookie (because that cookie exists, and browser send it automatically) in initial, not yet AJAX request, so CSRF is also the case.

Comment: Based on your answer I think that pretty good solution would be to store token in HttpOnly cookie, then read it on initial request, save it in Redux JS store (which is in use), and then use `Authorization` header on every next REST request. As I understand both in the case of architecture described in initial question and that here the CSRF protection is needed. What do you think about it?

Comment: In that case yes, you must also care about CSRF if you use the token from the cookie too. CSRF is an issue if authentication information is automatically sent by the browser, ie. if the session id or token is in a cookie. If only a request header is used for auth, you are good without further protection against CSRF. I'm not very familiar with Redux, but if the cookie is httpOnly, you won't be able to access it from Javascript at all, so you won't be able to store it with Redux JS. Storing the JWT in a httpOnly cookie makes it more secure, but usescases will be limited.